# Windows Server 2008 Black Screen on boot

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, server-crashes

I have a windows server 2008 running in Parrallels (on Mac osx)... the mac crashed yesterday and so I hard rebooted it, when I fired up the Windows Server 2008 VM this morning it goes as far as the progress bar then goes black screen and does nothing else (even when left for a long time).

I can boot into safe mode, Event Viewer says:

"The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load:
spldr
stoflt"

Any ideas?  What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert to your backup. :)

spldr is the "security loader", a driver of sorts. I'm not sure about this stuff in particular, but it sounds like you should try to rebuild the boot files. It has worked for me in a similar situation, though I don't recall the exact fail.

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/927392/?p=1) article explains how to. Good luck!

Comment: thanks that worked brilliantly  just loaded OS CD and ran bootsec and now has booted fine!

Comment: Super! I am happy it worked for you.